# tslint: Assign an HTMLElement to an Element var

Tags: typescript, tslint

TypeScript code:

```
var el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
if (el != null) {
  el = el.parentElement;
}
```

tslint gives error:

```
Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
```

I thought HTMLElement was a subclass of Element. What gives?

Comment: Your code errors with `"';' expected"`, what are you trying to do here? Are you assigning a value to `el` or are you comparing?

Comment: When changed to `el != null && (el = el.parentElement);` there are no compilation errors: [code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20el%20%3D%20document.elementFromPoint(2%2C%203)%3B%0Ael%20!%3D%20null%20%26%26%20(el%20%3D%20el.parentElement)%3B)

Comment: On closer inspection compilation succeeds and the problem is with tslint.

Comment: If this is a question that you still want answered, what's the tslint that is failing? And if it is a problem with tslint, have you raised it as an [issue](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues)?